# How to deal with multiple concurrent REST calls in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Background:** I'm building a web application (Mongo, Express, Angular and Node) to retrieve some data from a DB and display some charts on the client.
The charts are dynamic (thanks to D3 and Crossfilter) and the user can interact with the charts to filter the data and display only a subset of it.

For every interaction (clicks) with the charts, I'm making a REST call to the server (Using angular $http.get) to retrieve the relevant data and update asynchronously a table.

**Problem:** It is possible for the user to click several times and very quickly. Because the REST calls are asynchronous, there is no guarantee that the last piece of data received is the correct one, right?

**So, my question is**: how can I handle multiple and "concurrent" asynchronous REST calls in Angular? Is there a mechanism (correlation ID or so on) to be sure that the data I will display are the latest one?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please at least tell me why I'm down voted?

Comment: you can send a timestamp from the client if you have to make a lot of parallel calls and return this timestamp with the response too. I do not know why this was down voted. Maybe because this is not an angular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this the simplest solution is to prevent any further user interaction until the last set of requested data is returned. This also improves performance as needless calls are not being made.